# Extend the maximum input time and maximum execution time on openshift

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, openshift, haproxy

I wonder if there is a way to extend the maximum execution time and maximum input time with a PHP scaled app on openshift. I need to make an ajax request that need about 5 minutes to excute completely. I tried add some config to set php_value in .htaccess file but it didn't work. I think the problem is the Time Latency is too long, maybe more than 1 minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 minutes is a LONG time to have something making an ajax request.  Can you break the request up into shorter chunks or anything?  I'd be more concerned about fixing that issue than making the PHP request run longer.